# Xamarin.Ios App terminates while starting (in Simulator and iPhone) only stating "The App has been terminated"

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

I am developing a Xamarin App for Android and iOS on windows. For iOS compiling, I pair with a Mac Mini.

I was forced to update MacOS, XCode, VisualStudio for Mac and therefore Xamarin. On Windows I also updated from Visual Studio 2015 to 2017.

After the updates, Android version works still fine.

The iOS App pairs, compiles and provisions successfully, but whe the App starts (either on simulator or real device), it shows the launch screen and after a few seconds quits back to home screen. It even says "successfully launched" but then terminates

The only logs I get are:

- "The app has been terminated" -> on windows, in Debug Window
- "Service exited due to SIGABRT" -> on mac, in simulator log file

I searched the web and tried lots of stuff:

- Delete obj and bin folders
- Clean, Rebuild, Restart VS, Restart Mac, Restart PC, Restart....
- Deleted all Provisioning Files and Certificates, recreated them
- Used Automatic provisioning, used Manual provisioning
- Debug and Release Configuration
- iPhone Simulator and Real Device

Sadly nothing worked and I cannot get more info why this happens.

Does somebody have or had the same issue and found a solution? Do you have suggestion what more I can try?

I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks

Edit:
As requested, a Screeshot of my build properties:
[image: build properties]

Comment: For reference, I am using the Xamarin.Apple SDK 4.12.3.83

Comment: Have you tried restarting the device?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your build properties. Your Linker, architecture etc.

Comment: @Janwilx72 I restarted everything I could, to no avail. I will add a screenshot with build props to my post

Comment: Ok Thanks, hopefully I can help out

Comment: try Set your supported architecture to ARM64

Comment: there is no such choice, only x86_64. do I have to install and/or configure something in order to get arm64 support? for iPhone device, it is set to ARM64. Seems that Simulator has no other option

Comment: Change your active platform to device, and you'll see ARM64. Devices require 64bit architecture and Simulators require 32Bit

Comment: Yes I did it, but it does not work either

Comment: Have you tried checking the device logs on the mac mini?

Comment: Are you using VS 2019 on Mac but VS 2017 on Windows?

Comment: @Saamer Sorry for late response, I've been on vacation. Yes, I use VS2017 on Windows and latest VS for Mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally solved the problem...

I created a new iOS-Project from scratch, added the existing Xamarin.Forms project and copied the files from the original iOS project one by one. I also downgraded all firebase plugins from 5.x versions to the highest 4.x versions and xamarin forms from 3.x to 2.5.x and now the app runs in the simulator and bundle signing works also.

Thanks for your help, I hope my answer will help anyone with similar issues

Comment: Btw, I upgraded to Visual Studio 2019 both on Windows and MacOS

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. Restarting the device seems to be the only thing that works, but it's unreasonable to have to restart the device every time I want to run the debugger.

Comment: Unfortunatly restarting the device does not work for me

Comment: I should remove my answer, as restarting the device no longer works for me either.

I submitted a bug report. It is currently under investigation.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/612136/cannot-debug-xamain-ios-app-the-debugger-detaches.html